# Show/Hide Table without Javascript

Tags: html, css, html-table, html-email

I am sending an HTML email with large data tables of information, It would be really useful if I could hide these until a user clicked an expand button or something, but I'm not sure how to do this without using Javascript? Can it be done?

Comment: i would say stupid question. if you could make the user click any button, its much better to redirect him to your site :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is impossible in a mail client. You need JavaScript.

Comment: To expand upon this a bit, most mail clients ignore javascript.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible without the use of Javascript. If it was something as simple as a mouse-over, you might could use CSS like the following *(depending on the e-mail client)*:

```
#yourDiv { display: none; }
#yourDiv:hover { display: block; }
```

but otherwise, you **need** to use Javascript for this purpose.

**[CSS Support by E-mail Client (Lotus Notes should be in the Complete Guide PDF)](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/)**

Comment: You never know what CSS classes mail clients are going to support either. CSS techniques probably won't work with Outlook.

Comment: Thanks for that Dave :) Brain isn't working fast enough today. (or as fast as the hands are)

Comment: well its going to be in lotus notes, but thanx guys, ill see if I can hack something up!

Comment: In case you are interested, I added a CSS E-mail client support link in my answer. Might be useful for whatever solution you decide on.

Answer (score 0):

> Im not sure how to do this without using javascript?

Well, in theory you could try something like:

```
<input> <table>…</table>
```

and

```
input + table { display: none; }
input:focus + table { display: table; }
```

… but aside from being a hideously ugly hack, it isn't likely to work in email clients.

JavaScript is a more sensible option, but again, not supported by email clients.

The simplest solution would be to **keep the data table on a website and include a link to it in the mail.**